# Laravel/PHP JSON format from existing mySQL databse

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel

I'm getting started with Laravel and PHP and I am using the 'Query Builder' methods in Laravel to query an existing mySQL database.

```
    public function showApi($id)
    {   
    $data = DB::table('Customers')->where('ID', $id)->get(); //Gets specific records

    return $data;
    }
```

This produces an Array of objects and the following JSON preview:

[image]

I am really looking for (and actually use to consuming) the following format:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So `FirstName` is the column name in your db and you want to convert that into `first_name`?

Comment: No sorry there two separate DB's the first is mine and is spat out as an Array of objects, the second is an open API on the web that has the desired JSON format I want.

Comment: But how are the columns in your database called? `FirstName`, `LastName` etc?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand the question. My DB column names are ID, FirstName, LastName and Email

Comment: That was the answer I needed. I'm writing an answer right now ;)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to change the properties of your models when they get converted into arrays (or json objects) is to override the `toArray()` method in your model. So if you don't already, you will have to start working with [Eloquent models](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent).

**Your model - Customer.php**

```
class Customer extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'Customer' // you'll need that because you're table differs from the convention ('customer')

    public function toArray(){
        $attributes = parent::toArray();
        $array = array();

        foreach($attributes as $key => $value){
            $newKey = snake_case($key);
            $array[$newKey] = $value;
        }

        return $array;
    }
}
```

What we're doing here is just getting the array of attributes from your parent and then looping through it and changing the key from *StudlyCase* to *snake_case*

If you need this functionality in all your models, it would be best to create a `BaseModel` which has this method and then let all the others extend from it.

In the end, your controller method would look like this:

```
public function showApi($id)
{   
    $customers = Customer::where('ID', $id)->get(); //Gets specific records

    return Response::json($customers);
}
```

**Edit**

As Marcin Nabiałek pointed out in the comments, your column `ID` is kind of special. Laravel would convert it into `i_d`. So to avoid that we need to exclude it

```
foreach($attributes as $key => $value){
    if($key == 'ID'){
        $array['id'] = $value;
    }
    else {
        $newKey = snake_case($key);
        $array[$newKey] = $value;
    }
}
```

If you have more of these "special cases" you can use the same method to handle them separately too...

Comment: But in this case you need to be careful because it won't fully work. For example 'ID` will be converted into `i_d` and not `id` so you need to exclude key `ID` and change it into lowercase.